# Add a number to a duplicated string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Hi I have a list of values

```
ls = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b",  "c"]
```

And i wish to add an enumerating number to duplicates if ive used that term correctly.

Essentially I wnat to end up with this:

```
ls = ["a", "2a", "b", "2b", "3b", "4b",  "c"]
```

or this

```
ls = ["1a", "2a", "1b", "2b", "3b", "4b",  "1c"]
```

I just want each element of the list to be unique

Comment: If you have this `{'b': 4, 'a': 2, 'c': 1}` is it okay for you ? And what have you try ?

Comment: This looks like a good exercise, you are running into any specific challenges?

Comment: The list on here is a representation of a larger list i am working with. In this larger list there are about 5000 elements with some elements duplicated multiple times. So I dont know which elements are duplicated or how many times

Comment: Don't change the original question. This ruins the effort put by other users to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the most effective way.

```
ls = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b",  "c"]

UniqueValues = set(ls)

for x in UniqueValues:
    number = 0
    for i in range(0,len(ls)):
        if ls[i] == x:
            number += 1
            if number >= 2:
                ls[i] += str(number)
```

but we get what you're looking for

```
print(ls)
['a', 'a2', 'b', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` and `unique` methods.

```
from numpy import unique
from collections import Counter

ls = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b",  "c"]

dup = dict(Counter(ls))
l_uniq = unique(ls)
print([key if i == 0 else key + str(i+1) for key in l_uniq for i in range(dup[key])])
```

Out:

```
['a', 'a2', 'b', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

So we need to check complete list each time so that if same value exists we can change the pointing value.

```
ls = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b",  "c",'a','a']

for index,value in enumerate(ls):

  if value in ls[index+1:]:

    for new in range(0,200000000):
      if not  f'{value}{new}' in ls:
        ls[index] = f'{value}{new}'
        break

print(ls)
```

Output:

```
['a0', 'a1', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b', 'c', 'a2', 'a']
```

Comment: this works great thanks, how can i modify this to add the number to the start of the string instead?

Comment: I am changing current index value if same value is found, you can add if condition that if same value is found at index n change that value not existing value